# How can I fill my incomplete database with freebase?

Tags: freebase

I'm new to Freebase but how can I fill my incomplete database with Freebase? For example in my database I've an item sword, it has the attribute enchanted, frost, fire and orc. In Freebase I've additionally the legendary and weight attribute. How can I put this all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install [Google Refine](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/) and import (as CSV files) the tables from your database which you wish to augment with Freebase data.

Once you've imported your data into Google Refine you'll need to [reconcile](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/wiki/Reconciliation) each row against Freebase. This is necessary because Freebase has millions of topics and many of them have similar or identical names. For example, there are currently 26 topic in Freebase with the name "Sword" so you'll need to tell Google Refine which one of those corresponds to the row named "Sword" in your database.

When you've reconciled your data, you can [automatically extend each row](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/wiki/ExtendingDataFromFreebase) of data with additional values from Freebase. If you ask on the [Google Refine mailing list](https://groups.google.com/group/google-refine) they'll be able help you with the details of how to do that in the latest version of Refine.

When your data is fully augmented and cleaned up in Refine, you can export it back out to a CSV file and load it back into your database. You should also consider [adding columns to your database](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Data_linkage_guidelines) to store the reconciled Freebase object IDs so that you can repeat the whole process without having to re-reconcile all your data.